# Startup problems with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.4 on my Mac Pro, and on occasion, when rebooting or starting it up after it's recently been on, I get two issues.  The first is a blue login screen, so I can't see the login panel.  I can get to this if I remote in using LogMeIn however.  Once I've logged in, sometimes the keyboard doesn't work, and the mouse moves but does not let me click on anything.  The odd thing is that when booting up cold, it works just fine.

I've repaired permissions and checked the disk for errors, all that is ok.  I've also ran AppleJack to see if that helped, but I still get the issue.  Has anyone seen this before, and any ideas what I can do to fix this?  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the computer while [holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for verbose mode or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> for single user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) and hopefully that will give you a clue as to where your startup sequence is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit impatient, so I would just try to reinstall Mac OS X. The Snow Leopard installer should replace your current system with a fresh new one while leaving your current user data and settings intact.